# how to take the data from an entry to a variable in python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from ctypes import sizeof
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as tkk
from turtle import width
from selenium import *
import webbrowser

new = 1

window = tk.Tk()

def Done():
   global species
   string= species.get()
   furry.configure(text=string)

furry = tk.Label(
    text="This is a furry pic generator enjoy",
    foreground="Black",
    width=60,
    height=5
)
furry.pack()

species = tk.Entry()
species.pack(fill=tk.X)

x = species.get()

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + species.get()

def openweb():
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)

Furrygen = tk.Button(
    text="Get a furry",
    width=25,
    height=2,
    fg="Black",
    command=openweb
)
Furrygen.pack(fill=tk.X)

window.mainloop()
```

that's my code what I want is to take the data from the entry of species and add it to the search of google to open in a new tab with the search already done
I have done everything but for some reason, it doesn't want to put the data from the entry on the search tag why is that?

Comment: You are calling `.get()` on the Entry *immediately after creating it* - how could there possibly be any text typed into it yet???  You need to do the `.get()` in response to the Button being clicked.

Comment: Put the line that sets `url` inside the `openweb()` function.

Comment: both of those didnt fix it i tried putting it after the press of the button and i tried putting the URL in the openweb() and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the .get() to your openweb() function solved the issue when I tested it.  Look at the print statments I added and you can see it is in fact grabbing the input.  You should also reformat your script for readability and to take out redundancies.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as tkk
import webbrowser


new = 1

def openweb():
    value = species.get()
    species.delete("0", tk.END)
    print(value)
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + value
    print(url)
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)

    
def Done():
   global species
   string= species.get()
   furry.configure(text=string)


window = tk.Tk()

furry = tk.Label(text="This is a furry pic generator enjoy", foreground="Black",
                 width=60, height=5)
furry.pack()

species = tk.Entry()
species.pack(fill=tk.X)

Furrygen = tk.Button(text="Get a furry", width=25, height=2,
                     fg="Black", command=openweb)
Furrygen.pack(fill=tk.X)

window.mainloop()
```